# Convert enum to class and vice versa

Tags: java, enums

Currently, we have an business entity can be represented both as an enum or as a class.

The class implementation is easier and make business logic more clear. But there is probability of 50% that the requirements will change and an enum representation will make our life easier.

Concrete example

An entity has title and color. Color is editable, so there 2 ways

1. entity is an enum - there is another class with mapping from entity to its color.
2. entity is a class - just one more fiels for color, no problems.

Future change requirement - there should be rules associated with each entity

1. entity is an enum - the rules are hard coded in the code
2. entity is a class - there are needed few more classes for mapping and also an UI that will allow user to specify them.

In case the set of rules is static, the second option is an overkill.

So, in case we will need to transform the class to enum, are there any recommendations about this process ?

EDIT

The set of entities is limited and unlikely to be changed by user.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You should use `enums` only if you're gonna have limited and constant values. Otherwise, it should be a class. By the way it looks, you have a class design problem more than a *find a way for enum to class*.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza - the set of entities is limited, so that's already considered.

Comment: BTW, in Java Enums _are_ allready Classes. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html

Comment: @Lauri - yep, but the approaches are different when working with them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you want some functionality from enums and some from classes, then you could use mix of these:

```
  public class ColoredTitle
    {

        private String color;
        private Title title;

        public ColoredTitle(String color, Title title)
        {
            this.color = color;
            this.title = title;
        }

        public String getColor()
        {
            return color;
        }

        public void setColor(String color)
        {
            this.color = color;
        }

        public String getHeading()
        {
            return title.heading;
        }

        enum Title
        {
            FRONT_PAGE("Front Page"),
            FOOTER_TITLE("Footer Title");

            private String heading;

            Title(String title)
            {
                this.heading = title;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

If it has anything editable, you will need an entity class at some point anyway so go for the entity class first.

In case you have later a requirement for implementing a fixed set of rules, implement them as an enum with the hard coded rules, and add a field on your entity class that maps to that enum.

You can map enum on entity fields like this:

```
enum MyRule {
    RULE1, RULE2;
    // implement hard-coded rule
}

@Entity
class Myentity {
    @Enumerated(/* optionally specify EnumType, default is ordinal */)
    @Column
    MyRule rule;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `Entity` means `JPA entities.`

You can use `enum` to return out to out side world and inside entity you can have property that represents it.

```
@Entity
class Entity {
    @Column
    Integer ruleIndex = 0;//Illustration purpose only

    public Color getColor() {
        // ruturn color based on rule that will be applied by ruleindex
    }

}
enum Color {
    BLUE(0), BLACK(1), WHITE(2);

    private int ruleIndex = 0;
    private Color(int ruleIndex) {
        this.ruleIndex = ruleIndex;
    }
}
```

**Update**

It is not advisable to use enums as entities. Instead you can use Single inheritance strategy

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="DISC", discriminatorType=STRING,length=20)
public class Color
{......}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("Blue")
public class Blue extends Color
{......}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("Green")
public class Green extends Color
{......}
```

This will allow you to store all the data in the same table and will allow you to also identify data based on objects.

Comment: The colors are really editable, I mean - there won't be predefined values. But as we have a limited set of entities, it may worth, in some cases, to have them as enums.

Comment: Then you shouldn't It is advisable to have a base class and various values as entities with `Single Table Inheritance strategy`.

Comment: @AndreiPodoprigora Check the update. I think this is what you should do.

Answer (score 0):

Enums can have methods just like ordinary classes.

```
public enum Tree {

   FIR("Fir Tree"),
   BIRCH("Birch Tree");

   private String desc;

   public Tree(String desc) { this.desc = desc; }

   public String getDesc() { return desc; }
   public String getRandom() { return "abc"; }

}
```

Comment: I know, but the values are hardcoded. In case the color is editable, there is no way set the new color for an entity without recompiling.